# heroku: node/mongo app not serving in sandbox mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

if i pull my app down fresh from git and run the following command(s), the app runs just fine locally (with expected API event errors bc ive hooked it to a blank mongodb instance)

```
nodemon server.js
node server.js
```

furthermore, the app builds successfully on heroku ...but does not serve! the only error message in the logs seems to be this:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shewhat.herokuapp.com request_id=e42d1304-c91b-4e72-b965-1d06ec363815 fwd="73.208.41.187" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

i have the app setup on heroku with a mLab mongoDB add-on installed

i have already set this:

```
export MONGOLAB_URI=" mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds029426.mlab.com:29426/my-db-name"
```

i have added a PROCFILE with one process line of "node server.js"

it is linked up with a github repo.

what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Install the Heroku toolbelt and start some [logging](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) ;-)

do something like:

```
 heroku logs --tail
```

and restart your dyno's

If you not already checked see this document: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

After your comment below, i noticed you added the PROCFILE later. I'm guessing Heroku set your dyno's scale to 0 :|.

You could execute:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Additional info: Please check this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-dynos-running

Comment: i had already checked the logs. my post contained the only error statement i could find.

Comment: Updated my answer